# Finding the next free time slot

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have a db table(Hibernate conf all done),

```
  ResourceRequest( resource, startTime, endTime, status )
```

between the startTime and endTime the resource is occupied.

**Problem Statement:**
For a input of *inStartTime* and *inEndTime*, I have to find the next available slot if it is already occupied in the given slot. 
Have to write a hibernate query for this.

**One quick solution that I could think of is:**
Querying the resourcerequests for the given resource into a collection and then manipulating it to get the next available slot.

But I want have that as my last resort. Any help is appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Is there a status value for when a resource is ***not*** occupied? Or if a resource is not occupied will there simply be no record for that period of time?  If `not occupied` is represented with no record, can that be changed to having a record with a status code for unoccupied?  And can two records for the same resource ever overlap? Finally, how are you representing the times? If a resource is occupied for one hour, starting at mid-day, it is normal to have `startTime = 12:00` and `endTime = 13:00` *(inclusive start, exclusive end)* - Is that what you are doing?

Comment: @Dems
* There is no flag like occupied/unoccupied. The status column is to denote the approval status[which is not used here]
    'resource1' '09/08/2012 12:00' '09/08/2012 13:00' approved
* records will not overlap.
* startTime-12:00 and endTime-13:00 is normal. but 2 slots dont overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in sql

```
SELECT * FROM slots s1 WHERE
    s1.endTime > :inStartTime AND
    not exists (SELECT 1 FROM slots s2 WHERE s2.startTime > s1.endTime AND s2.startTime < DateAdd(s1.endTime, :inEndMinusInStart))
ORDER BY
    s1.startTime


// and criteria to tweak

DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.for(Slot.class)
    .add(<filter on resource>)
    .add(Restrictions.propertyGt("startTime", "s1.endTime"));
    .add(Restrictions.propertylt("startTime", Projections.sqlFunction("dateadd", Projections.property("s1.endTime"), inStartTime - inEndTime, Hibernate.dateTime));

session.createCriteria(Slot.class, "s1")
    .add(<filter on resource>)
    .add(Restrictions.gt(endTime, inStartTime))
    .add(Subqueries.notExists(subquery))
```

hope it helps